# Switch screen on by application (ANDROID, debug, all rights possible)

Tags: android

I read all there is about wake locks and so on. But I want something different. I have three devices to test, and mainly one device sucks really hard. Its the Asus transformer. The main problem, it can't be charged over USB. This means, if I tell it to "stay enabled during debug" the battery is dead after a while.

Also I want to write a small script deploying my app to all three devices once I build (no problem), starting them (no problem), and then **ENABLE THE SCREEN** (no way till now).

If found this intent, was happy for 23.5 seconds, and then read this:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_SCREEN_ON

Is there any way for me to enable the screen. The device is black, the screen is locked, my app starts (this works, seeing debug messages and hear startup sound), but i would have to manually unlock the screen.

I know, its not THAT bad, but when developing UIs I would have to do this like 100 times a day, and this is annyoing. The two little ones could stay on, but the big one (Transformer) would be empty after a while. I just had a thought, maybe I can tell the Transformer only to dim after a while, and to "undim" on startup. Would increase lifetime tenfold.

But still, if anyone knows a way to turn the screen on, that would be fantastic!

Chris

**[UPDATE]**
Ok, what you can do is reduce the screen brightness after some time, by using this:

```
    WindowManager.LayoutParams WMLP = getWindow().getAttributes();
    WMLP.screenBrightness = 0.01F;
    getWindow().setAttributes(WMLP);
```

Dont use 0 as a value (at least not until this question is answered), because the screen will switch off, and you will never get in on again. At least without using your thumb and pressing a button, sooo oldschool...

Comment: Perhaps you could leave the Transformer connected to the charger and use adb over a wireless network instead of usb?

Comment: Uh, nice idea, never tried adb over wireless. Will check google for tips how to do this. Result: Need root (which I dont have, and not in the mood to try). And also could cause more trouble. If I dim the display (setting to bright for 5 min after startup of app), the battery life should go up to 5+ hours. Will try other power saving stuff, so plugging it in once a day to charge should be enough...

Comment: Actually adb over wireless does not ultimately require root, but it's a pain to set up each time without it, so if you have an easier solution go with that.